# How can I make a systemd --user timer stay enabled after reboot?

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04

System is: Ubuntu 16.04.

`~/.config/systemd/user/mpd.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=mpd timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

`~/.config/systemd/user/mpd.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=mpd

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/redacted/temp/mpd-service/mpd.sh
Type=oneshot
```

Ran: `systemctl --user start mpd.timer`, the service runs succesfully, and is listed under `systemctl --user list-timers`.

Ran: `systemctl --user enable mpd.timer`, which created a symlink in `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants`.

After reboot `systemctl --user enable mpd.timer` shows empty. Also tried with `timers.target` for `WantedBy` of `mpd.timer`. The result was the same.

Ran: `systemctl --user --type=target --all`, shows `default.target` and `timers.target` loaded and active.

Tried: `systemctl --user daemon-reload`.

Tried: `sudo loginctl enable-linger redacted`.
Ran: `loginctl show-user redacted`. Shows: `Linger=yes`. The result was the same.

I've searched for similar problems, but couldn't find anything else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be nothing wrong with your setup, just a misunderstanding about how systemd works. If you enable a unit twice, systemctl will not show anymore output the second time, since it already created the symlink, it will not tell you that it already is enabled

You can check if the timer is enabled and was started and is running with `systemctl --user status mpd.timer`.

The first line prints the name and description, the second line (the one that starts with `Loaded:`) tells you the location of the file and if it is enabled, and third line (`Active:`), tells you if it's active (running) and since when. It should also tell you if there were errors or failures.

Cf. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

Update: Sorry, I was wrong about lingering.

Comment: I get:

`Loaded: loaded (/home/redacted/.config/systemd/user/mpd.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: Odd. I can't reproduce this behaviour. Is the timer running when you start it manually? `systemctl --user start mpd.timer`